# How to change position of custom menu for rotated TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to have two TextFields, one of them 180° rotated. When I want to select the text I have typed for rotated one and use context menu buttons (copy, paste, cut, select all) the menu goes beyond the screen as seen in provided screenshot.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Transform.rotate(
              angle: -math.pi,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                child: const TextField(),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: const TextField(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Text field context menu issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0qiY.png)

How can I shift this menu to be above or below the text and fit into the screen?